# Text edit problems with Elementor with conflict from prior web builder

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have installed Elementor on my WordPress. Previously I built the page with Themeco Cornerstone. I wish to keep the pages made by Cornerstone for now and build new pages in Elementor and eventually redesign the old pages with Elementor.

My problem is when I go to edit the text in Elementor, I can not change the font or change the color. The only way to change the font is to go into the WordPress settings and change it there (but this changes the font across the whole site).I can change the text and and colors for the headline - just not text body. I'm told that its a problem with Cornerstone over riding the settings. I don't want to delete it as I have pages built with it. Any idea what I can do?

Thanks in advance

Asked a freelancer on Upwork who didn't know, tried a few YouTube videos for the answer.